# Git+composer in a multidependency structure and multiple environments

Tags: git, deployment, composer-php, production

My company has an API using git and composer to manage its dependencies. The main project has like 50 dependencies, all of them belonging to the company. Some of them have regular code changes, and others are not updated in months.

At this moment the composer.json in the main project has all dependencies pointing to dev-dev, but we want to keep dev for development purposes and use master for production environment.

This means that composer.json should contain dev-dev for devs environment, but dev-master for prod environment. We've thought of using two composers (composer.dev.json and composer.prod.json) and when updating dependencies, use the following command:

```
COMPOSER=composer.dev.json composer update
```

This way we could use both of them depending on the environment. What we don't like about this approach is that dependencides must be replicated in both composers, or in other words, when devs include a dependency in composer.dev.json, they must remember to add it to composer.prod.json too. This keeps us back from using this approach, as we'd like the process to be more automatic and avoid issues when a dev forgets to include the dependency in the other composer file.

What's the best way to manage this kind of applications with so many dependencies, thinking of production deployment?

It would be perfect if composer included an argument to set the branch to download, something like this:

```
composer update --branch=dev-dev #Development environment
composer update --branch=dev-master #Production environment
```

Yeah, I know this is not how it is supposed to work, but would solve our problem :)

Any ideas here will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The question is what is leading here. If the dev/prod parallel rails are leading, you can't skip them. With it your problem statement is also clear:

> What we don't like about this approach is that dependencides must be replicated in both composers, or in other words, when devs include a dependency in composer.dev.json, they must remember to add it to composer.prod.json too. This keeps us back from using this approach, as we'd like the process to be more automatic and avoid issues when a dev forgets to include the dependency in the other composer file.

Composer files are files containing **only** [JSON Text](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259). This is no magic, and while a text-diff might not be the best practical approach, writing a simple PHP script to compare those two files for the relevant parts should be a no-brainer in a PHP shop.

A simple `make clean all` should immediately reveal any missing parts while you naturally edit only one file. Or in other words: Delegate that problem to your build manager, define dependencies and targets and then just make it.

With build automation start where your needs are. Identifying pain-points can help to figure out where that is.

This also works for your alternative scenario. What if composer had this branch feature? Pardon me? You need to create two JSON Text files which are identical *but* at some very specific places under `composer.json#/require` you exchange always the same substring? Perhaps I'm not fully understanding your problem, but with all due respect, no need to patch composer for that:

- `make COMPOSER_BRANCH=dev`
- `make COMPOSER_BRANCH=master`

A good build manager comes with parametrization and can handle them on the command-line (and in your case there is likely even a default), just make it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The script to check if both files contain the same dependencies is something we had in mind, although we just wanted to know if there was a better scenario using just one composer for many environments. However, I see we'll need to end up uding two files, so will add to our pipelines the required commands to check both files are up to date and are valid containing the same dependencies.

Comment: Why not make those two files the result of the build, then when the build is green, you don't need to discuss whether or not the files are valid. Always have one source instead of figuring out later if multiple sources are in sync. Just my 2 cents.